# Why mysql return error on group concat at subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have mysql error `Subquery returns more than 1 row` on this query with `GROUP_CONCAT`. Why I gat this error and how i can solve this problem?

```
 select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.url, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(
        (select name 
             from labels_data ld, 
                  labels l 
             where ld.id=l.site_id=s.id 
         limit 2),
        ', '),
 ... more valid sql code ...
 as labels from sites s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `group_concat` into the subquery.  The subquery *is* returning more than one row (at least normally).  It has a `limit 2`.

```
  (select group_concat(name , ', ')
    from labels_data ld join
         labels l 
         on ld.id=l.site_id=s.id 
    limit 2
  )
```

I also recommend that you use proper ANSI join syntax.

Comment: +1 -- but is that JOIN syntax correct?  ld.id=l.site_id=s.id?  Here's a sample Fiddle moving it to the WHERE clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dd09/1